# How to define a variable string format specifier

Tags: objective-c, format-specifiers

I have this line of code

```
// valueX is a long double (long double is a huge floating point)
NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.10Lg", valueX];
```

This format specifier is specifying up to 10 decimal digits but I don't want to hard code this to 10.

I have this variable `numberOfDigits` that I want to be used to define the number of digits. For those itching to down vote this question, it is not so easy as it seems. I cannot substitute the `10` with `%@` because `%.10Lg` is a format specifier by itself.

OK, I can create a bunch of strings like `@"%.5Lg"`, `@"%.8Lg"`, `@"%.9Lg"`... and switch that, but I wonder if there is another way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is, if you read the manual pages for format specifiers.  You can replace the precision with `*`, which means it will get taken from a parameter instead.

```
int numDigits = 10;
NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*Lg", numDigits, valueX];
```

I couldn't find this in the core foundation reference, but I know that this is written in the `man 3 printf` man page.

Comment: BRILLIANT!!!!!!   This is why you have 127K points and I am struggling to have 14K 

Comment: I've just been doing this for a long time, that's all.

Comment: Thanks Dietrich. I was trying (and failing) to remember the syntax of the variable # of digits in a format specifier, and you saved me digging up my copy of the K&R C book.

Answer (score 1):

Dietrich's answer is the simplest and therefore best. Note that even if there wasn't a built-in way to specify the number of digits with a parameter you could still have done it by first building your format string and then using it:

```
- (NSString *) stringFromValue: (long double) value digits: (int) digits; {

  //First create a format string. Use "%%" to escape the % escape char.
  NSString *formatString =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%%.%dLg", digits];

  return [NSString stringWithFormat: formatString, value];
}
```

Comment: I forgot that bit. (Edited.)